# How to refresh a page until an element is available using python (Selenium)?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to design a code where it tends to refresh the page until the particular element is visible in on the webpage using selenium. I have designed the following code but it gave me an error.

> Error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"BUY NOW"}

Code:

```
while True:
    if driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('BUY NOW'):
        break
    driver.refresh()

buy = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('BUY NOW')

buy.click()
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

selenium raises exceptions if it failed to find single element.
so your loop (while True) cannot be a successful loop, the code "if driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('BUY NOW')" may break the script.

there are two ways to do it:

1. use 'WebDriverWait' to wait the element explicitly. (suggest to use WebDriverWait)
   example:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(("partial link text","BUY NOW")))
    driver.refresh()
```

2. use find_elements instead.
   example:

```
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    
    while True:
        if len(driver.find_elements(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'BUY NOW')) > 0:
            break
        driver.refresh()
    
    buy = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('BUY NOW')
    buy.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give some time for the element to show up. Try using waits:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

while True:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 1)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('BUY NOW'))
    if driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('BUY NOW'):
        break
    driver.refresh()
```